# count of distinct with eliminating repeating values

Tags: sql

I have a table similar to this

```
AA  20170101
BB  20170101
CC  20170101
AA  20170102
CC  20170102
DD  20170102
BB  20170103
EE  20170103`
```

and I need to get the count of distinct values for each day. the tricky part is you cannot count the same value for different days. ex : AA should count only once for all days. The final result should be similar to this.

```
3 20170101--> (this is AA, BB, CC)
1 20170102--> (this is DD)
1 20170103--> (this is EE)`
```

when I try below it gives me incorrect result since same value is counting more than once for each day.

```
select count(distinct(name)),date
from testcount
group by date
```

also this final query should be a set based question.no loops etc.

Comment: Why is it counting more than once? Is it a date or datetime column?

Comment: AA,BB,CC only two values are there for different dates

Comment: This is like *the number of new customer per day*? What's you DBMS?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need nested aggregates:

```
select first_date, count(*) 
from 
 (
   select name, 
      min(date) as first_date -- find the first date for each name, only count once
   from testcount 
   group by name
 ) as d
group by first_date
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two aggregates, the first is to get the first date for each name, then you can count the dates by name:

```
SELECT  Date, COUNT(Name) AS Names
FROM    (   SELECT  Name, MIN(Date) AS Date
            FROM    T
            GROUP BY Name
        ) AS t
GROUP BY Date;
```